# Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: _vm.next is not a function"

Tags: vue.js

I have the error:

```
 TypeError: _vm.next is not a function
    at click (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"71d6e50a-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/QuestionBox.vue?vue&type=template&id=62ab2b85& (app.js:986), <anonymous>:54:30)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854)
    at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2175)
    at HTMLButtonElement.original._wrapper (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6917)
```

This is my `QuestionBox.vue` component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <b-jumbotron header="BootstrapVue" lead="Bootstrap v4 Components for Vue.js 2">

            <template v-slot:lead>
               {{currentQuestion.question}}
            </template>

    <hr class="my-4">

    <b-list-group>
        <b-list-group-item v-for="(answer, index) in answers" :key="index">{{ answer }}</b-list-group-item>
    </b-list-group>
    <b-button variant="primary" class="mt-3" href="#">Submit</b-button>
    <br>
    <b-button @click="next()" variant="success" class="mt-3">Next Question</b-button>
    </b-jumbotron>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default{
    props: {
        next: Function,
        currentQuestion: Object,
    },
    computed: {
    answers(){
        let answers = [...this.currentQuestion.incorrect_answers]
         answers.push(this.currentQuestion.correct_answer)
         return answers
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

My `App.vue` component:

```html
<QuestionBox 
      v-if="questions.length>0"
      :function="next"
      :currentQuestion="questions[index]"/>
```

Comment: In `App.vue` you're passing a prop called `function` but in the child you're calling it `next`. You probably want something like `:next="next"` in `App.vue`, though arguably you'd be better off using events.

Comment: Thank you! It worked